# RAILS, CUCUMBER: Getting the testing server address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

While running a cucumber test, I need to know the local testing server address.  It will be something like "localhost:47632".  I've searched the ENV but it isn't in there, and I can't seem to find any other variables that might have it.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the port is generated is dynamically generated on test runs. You can use OS level tools to inspect what connections are opened by process and glean the port that way. I do this on my ubuntu system infrequently so I can't tell you off the top of my head what tool does that. Netstat maybe? I always have to go out and google for it so consider this more of a hint than a complete answer.

Ah, to be more clear...I put a debug breakpoint in, and when it breaks THEN I use the OS level tools to see what port the test server is running on at that moment in time. How to discover it predictively? No idea, sorry.

here's what I use:

netstat -an | grep LISTEN

Comment: Using jaydel's idea, here's the code. I extract the line from netstat that has the current pid. (Probably not the most elegant way to do this, but it works)

    value = %x( netstat -l -p --tcp )
    pid = $$.to_s
    local_port = ""
    value.split( "\n" ).each do |i|
        if i.include?( pid )
            m = i.match( /\*:(\d+)/ )
            local_port = m[1].to_s
        end
    end

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question just so that the code formatting will be correct)...
Using jaydel's idea to use netstat, here's the code. I extract the line from netstat that has the current pid.  (Probably not the most elegant way to do this, but it works)

```
value = %x( netstat -l -p --tcp )
pid = $$.to_s
local_port = ""
value.split( "\n" ).each do |i|
    if i.include?( pid )
        m = i.match( /\*:(\d+)/ )
        local_port = m[1].to_s
    end
end
```

Comment: On MacOS, the netstat command has to be "netstat -l -p tcp" (without the -- in front of tcp).